# User request with nuxt auth module and laravel sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt auth with laravel sanctum, it works but when i run there's a user request that i didn't manually made, I cant find any component/page that sends the user request. Did the nuxt auth module automatically sends it when serve? Thanks

[image: user request]

**nuxt.js.config**

```
auth: {
  login: '/login',
  logout: '/',
  strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/login', method: 'post', propertyName: false },
          logout: {url: '/logout', method: 'post', },
          user: { url: '/api/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
        },
        tokenRequired: false,
        tokenType: false
      }
    }
},
```

Comment: yes, nuxtjs send a request after the login to get user data from /api/user and put the data into the store so you can use them later, they made it automatically

Comment: @Thamer for the login i know it will send the user request ,, but im not trying to login. It just automatically appears

Comment: no, look at the third param "user" within the "endpoints" object, it came from that

Comment: @Thamer yes, but how did the user request being sent ? I understand that when a user login , nuxt will send the login request and user request. but right now when i run 'npm run serve' ,, the user request is being send automatically when the page starts, eventhough im not login in or trying to login

Comment: yes its not just for login request it is for detect logged in user.

Comment: @TEFO is there a way to remove it ?

Comment: if you remove it after refreshing the page you lost the users data

Comment: @HelloWorld1014 to remove this option, you just need to put false instead of passing an object to user attribute, like  user: false,

Comment: Can you see if that helps: https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/828#issuecomment-692036117